# SoapUI Open Source project test cases are running in indefinite loop

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a SoapUI project with Test Suite Setup scripts running the test cases multiple times based on a global property but it is running in indefinite loop. Please help me to fix the issue:

```
def project = null     
def workspace = runner.testSuite.project.getWorkspace();
def count=context.expand('${#Global#run}')


if (workspace != null) {
 project = workspace.getProjectByName("IQCX")
}
if (project.open && project.name == "IQCX") {
 def properties = new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap()    
 def testcase = project.getTestSuiteByName("TestSuite 1").getTestCaseByName("Login");    
 def testcase1 = project.getTestSuiteByName("TestSuite 1").getTestCaseByName("Logout");    
 if(testcase == null)
 {    
  throw new RuntimeException("Could not locate testcase 'TestCase'! ");
 } else {
// This will run everything in the selected project   
for(int i=1;i<=count;i++){
    if(i!=count){
         testcase.run(new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap(), false)
        sleep(70000)
         testcase1.run(new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap(), false)
         sleep(5000)
         log.info( "Finished running "+i+" cycle" )
    }
 else if(i==count){
    log.info "count is " + i
    runner.cancel("finish it")
    testcase=null
    return null
    break;
    }
    else{
        break;
        }
 }
 
    runner.cancel("finish it")
    testcase=null
    
return null
 }
} 
else {
 throw new RuntimeException("Could not find project")
}
```

Comment: What is the value of count and what is happening where you are logging the value of i on each iteration?

Comment: By the way, I don't think this relates to your problem but there's some things you could tidy up - eg I don't think you can reach the `else { break }`, also lots of nice neat things possible with groovy, eg forEach over a range https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Range.html and no need for semicolons - as I say I'm sure these things don't relate to your problem but often easier to figure out problems when code is neat and simple

Comment: count is 2 and it is never reaching to else block. It goes till  log.info( "Finished running "+i+" cycle" )  and again rerun:

Comment: If count is 2 then expectation is that you'd get `finished running 1`, then `count is 2`. Just to clarify, do you see `finished running 1` and then reruns? On the face of it that doesn't seem possible without seeing `count is 2`

Comment: My best guess initially was that an exception was thrown during a test case run and maybe SoapUI is configured to rerun on failure (I don't know enough to know if that is a thing). However what you say about the logged information means that is not what happened

Comment: It seems a bit mysterious based on the information. I'm afraid I'm heading off to sleep in a minute but as you can't debug this, best thing may be to (a) add more logging to see exactly where the code goes and (b) add a big try catch block round the whole thing and log inside the catch, including the exception

Answer (score 0):

This is resolve by converting def count to Integer. Thanks anyway